# SQLite. Поиск подстроки на определённом отрезке значения поля

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Предположим, что есть некая таблица `"exp"`. В ней есть поле `"id"` типа `Text`. Все содержащиеся значения будут иметь вид `"00010002300123"`.
Возможно ли средствами SQLite, например, с помощью `LIKE`, как-нибудь указать, что при поиске подстроки необходимо брать, например, символы с 1 по 4, с 5 по 8, с 9 по 11, с 12 и до конца?

Comment: В like помимо `%` обозначающего произвольное кол-во символов обычно есть еще `_` обозначающее один любой символ. так что вполне можно соорудить маску типа `like '____abcd%'` и получится с 5 по 8 как раз

Comment: А зачем для работы с целочисленным полем LIKE?

Comment: @newman, какое ж оно целочисленное, если там лидирующие нули?

Comment: @Qwertiy до правки вопроса было указано что поле типа Int. Да и лидирующие нули автор вопроса мог увидеть где-нибудь в менеджере базы - в котором именно так и настроен вывод.

Comment: @newman, как раз задумывались значения с лидирующими нулями. В структуре бд будет много зависимых таблиц и для некоторых из них требуются id такого вида, что бы определять без лишних запросов и лишних столбцов родительские объекты и отбирать записи по ним. То есть на пример забирать все записи относящиеся к родительской записи с id=1, что в маске будет отображаться как `LIKE '0001__________'` и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)! Действительно, получилась маска. Пример запроса в данном случае будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM `exp` WHERE `id` LIKE '0001__________';
```

И дальше по аналогии составлять отрезки